# How to add password fields to a default WordPress registration?

Tags: php, wordpress, passwords, registration

I woulrd like to enable users to choose their own passord, but keep a verification email(without reseting password link)?

I am adding an input field for the password in wp-login:

```
<input type="password" name="user_password" value="" placeholder="Password" id="user_password" class="input" />
```

Than, I have a custom plugin thats sets user's password:

```
function myplugin_registration_change_pass( $user_id ) 

{if ( isset( $_POST['user_password'] ) )
    wp_set_password( $_POST['user_password'], $user_id );}
```

For some reason I keep getting verification email asking the user to set a password.
ANy ideas how I can solve this?

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/theme-my-login/ This plugin supports that functionality. Maybe you could dig into the code and figure it out, or just use the plugin?

Comment: you added input field for the password in wp-login or registration?

Comment: Whenever you want to change the registration you are doing that in wp-login, from what i know.

Comment: can you post your full code?

Answer (score 3):

```
<form name="registerform" id="registerform" action="<?php echo esc_url( site_url( 'wp-login.php?action=register', 'login_post' ) ); ?>" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
<p>
    <label for="user_login"><?php _e('*First Name') ?><br />
    <input type="text" name="user_login" id="user_login" class="input" value="<?php echo esc_attr(wp_unslash($user_login)); ?>" size="25" /></label>
</p>
<p>
    <label for="user_login"><?php _e('*Last Name') ?><br />
    <input type="text" name="user_login" id="user_login" class="input" value="<?php echo esc_attr(wp_unslash($user_login)); ?>" size="25" /></label>
</p>


<p>

    <label for="user_login"><?php _e('*Username') ?><br />
    <input type="text" name="user_login" id="user_login" class="input" value="<?php echo esc_attr(wp_unslash($user_login)); ?>" size="25" /></label>
</p>
<p>
    <label for="user_email"><?php _e('*Email address') ?><br />
    <input type="email" name="user_email" id="user_email" class="input" value="<?php echo esc_attr( wp_unslash( $user_email ) ); ?>" size="25" /></label>
</p>

<p>
    <label for="user_login"><?php _e('*Choose a password') ?><br />
    <input type="text" name="user_password" id="user_password" class="input" value="<?php echo esc_attr(wp_unslash($user_login)); ?>" size="25" /></label>
</p>
<p>
    <label for="user_login"><?php _e('*Confirm password') ?><br />
    <input type="text" name="user_password" id="user_password" class="input" value="<?php echo esc_attr(wp_unslash($user_login)); ?>" size="25" /></label>
</p>
<p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike" onclick="return false" checked >I agree to the terms and conditions<br>
</p>
```

When you go to wp-login.php at some point you have these fields for user registration. I added first, last name and password.I also created a small plugin that sets the password from the input field:

```
function myplugin_set_pass( $user_id ) 
{if ( isset( $_POST['user_password'] ) )
wp_set_password( $_POST['user_password'], $user_id );}
add_action('user_register','myplugin_set_pass')
```

With the line line I am saying that on user registration the function from the plugin should be performed. In other words the password should be set. I am not really sure if that is the right track.

Comment: I just checked on my webserver. It works. Once a user register it can directly log in with the password. Now the question is how to create a verification email. The user now gets email that ask him to set the password(even tought  the password is already defined). Instead I want the user to recieve verification email(he is not able to login before click on the link from the email)

Comment: Another thing is the "Repeate password" field. Why we need to repeat the password?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
  function frontend_register(){     

    $gfemail        = $_POST['user_email'];
    $firstname      = $_POST['user_firstname'];
    $lastname       = $_POST['user_lastname'];
    $password       = $_POST['user_password'];      


    if (email_exists( $gfemail ) === false) {

      $password             =   esc_attr( $password );
      $email                =   sanitize_email( $gfemail );
      $first_name               =   sanitize_text_field( $firstname );
      $last_name                =   sanitize_text_field( $lastname );

      $userdata = array(
          'user_login'    =>        $email,
          'user_email'    =>    $email,
          'user_pass'     =>    $password,
          'role'                =>   'subscriber',
          'first_name'    =>    $first_name,
          'last_name'     =>    $last_name,
          );
      $new_user = wp_insert_user ( $userdata );       

      if(!is_wp_error($new_user)){          

        $headers = 'Content-type: text/html;charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'From: Your SiteName <test@test.com>' . "\r\n";

        $verifyCode = sha1($new_user.$email);

        update_user_meta( $new_user, 'email_confirmation_done', 'No');
        update_user_meta( $new_user, 'email_confirmation_code', $verifyCode);

        $subject = 'Please verify your account' . "\r\n";       

        $mkUrl = sprintf('<a href="%s?verifycode=%s&user_login=%s">click here</a>', $wpgsloginpage, $verifyCode, $email);
        $message = sprintf('<p>Dear %s,</p><br> ', $first_name);
        $message .= sprintf('<hr>');
        $message .= sprintf('<p><strong>Please verify your account by clicking on this link %s </strong></p>', $mkUrl);
        $message .= sprintf('<hr>');            
        $message .= sprintf('<br><p style="font-size:12.8px">Thank you for registering<br><br>');
        wp_mail($email, $subject, $message, $headers);  
        die("success");
      }
    }else{
        die("failure");
    }       

}


if ( ! function_exists( 'wp_new_user_notification' ) ) :
function wp_new_user_notification( $user_id, $deprecated = null, $notify = '' ) {
    return;
}
endif;
```

Comment: you have to check `email_confirmation_done` = yes while login

Comment: I use the code in wp-login and I changed the email_confirmation to yes. But I am still getting email with "Set password" and still getting this message that my user has auto-generated password. Furthermore, I want verification to be sent. Just saying for example "Activate you account here", but still.

Comment: I think I am doing something wrong. Do I need to add the code to wp-login or I should put it on plugin and add it when register action is performed? When i add the code to wp-login I still get message that the user has auto generated password and the user gets an email with set the password

Comment: are you using in default wordpress register?

Comment: It wont work my code for default . you have to create a template for register and post the value in ajax to my function.

Comment: Well I am supposed to use the default wp registration, so I cannot use it.

Comment: you are changing in core files?

Comment: Of course not, you can change wp-login, without any problem. It is better than creating custom registration.